# Error on "function getVersion public view returns (uint256)"

Tags: function

I get the error:
"ParserError: Expected '(' but got 'public'
--> contracts/FundMe.sol:10:25:
|
10 |     function getVersion public view returns (uint256) {
|                         ^^^^^^

function getVersion () public view"
in the code:
"// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity >=0.6.6 <0.9.0;
import "@chainlink/contracts/src/v0.8/interfaces/AggregatorV3Interface.sol";
contract FundMe {
mapping(address => uint256) public addressToAmountFunded;
function fund() public payable {
addressToAmountFunded[msg.sender] += msg.value;
//what the ETH -> USD conversion rate
}
function getVersion public view returns (uint256) {
AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface();
}
}"
the error is in public on the function: "function getVersion public view returns (uint256)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing parenthesis in our `getVersion` function.

```
function getVersion() public view returns (uint256) {
        AggregatorV3Interface priceFeed = AggregatorV3Interface();
    }
```

Comment: Hello. I am following a YouTube tutorial and the tutorial comes without a parenthesis. I have tried with the parenthesis and it creates another problem. It gives me the error "Estimated execution cost: 320 gas

function getVersion () public view returns (uint256 internal )
contracts/FundMe.sol 9:4

Warning: Function state mutability can be restricted to pure
  --> contracts/FundMe.sol:10:5:
   |
10 |     function getVersion () public view returns (uint256) {
   |     ^ (Relevant source part starts here and spans across multiple lines)."

Comment: The problem is fixed, later in the tutorial, he does add the parenthesis. Thank you.